# Add number of observations per group in barplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to add the number of observations to my plot, but I don't know if I am approaching this right. 
I drew a my plot using the ggplot2 and tidyverse packages.

What I want is to add the number of observations (in the Obs column of the data) on top of each of the columns of the graph. However, it looks like I am not doing it right because it takes the value for each part of the column.

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thank you very much!

**Code for the graph**

```
Euk_one %>% 
  drop_na(`Length Stretch`) %>%
  mutate_at(c("GGA","GGG","GGT","GGC"),~.x/`Length Stretch`) %>% 
  group_by(interval) %>% select(c(interval, "GGA","GGG","GGT","GGC", Obs))%>%
  summarize_all(mean) %>%pivot_longer(-c(interval, Obs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=interval, y=value, fill=name)) + geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Eukarya 1 Codon Stretches - Distribution of codons ")+
  labs(fill= "Codons") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + geom_text(aes(label=Obs), vjust = -.25)
```

**Example Data**

```
structure(list(interval = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("[6,7]", 
"(7,8]", "(8,9]", "(9,10]"), class = "factor"), `Length Stretch` = c(8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6), GGA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 
0), GGG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GGT = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 0, 
0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 6), GGC = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Length Gene` = c(5250, 
5250, 3021, 1905, 2910, 2973, 2367, 3021, 2931, 2754, 2424, 2862, 
2436, 5061, 4935, 23949, 23988, 24024, 2733, 2733, 2358, 2358, 
2733, 2733, 2838, 2079, 2100, 1998, 2835, 1197, 1197, 2838, 1998, 
3795, 3795, 3795, 1320, 1827, 2088, 663, 10395, 10545, 2340, 
2340, 1323, 1977, 2085, 4773, 10557, 10554, 1920), NumGens = c(19297, 
19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 
19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 
19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 
19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 
19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 
19297, 19297, 19297, 19297, 19297), Count = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), Obs = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -51L
))
```

**Example of the plot**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you have only one value to plot as a label per interval, you can filter your dataframe using `distinct` function from `dplyr` and set a single y value to plot it:

```r
library(tidyverse)
Euk_one %>% 
  drop_na(`Length Stretch`) %>%
  mutate_at(c("GGA","GGG","GGT","GGC"),~.x/`Length Stretch`) %>% 
  group_by(interval) %>% dplyr::select(c(interval, "GGA","GGG","GGT","GGC", Obs))%>%
  summarize_all(mean) %>%pivot_longer(-c(interval, Obs)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=interval, y=value, fill=name)) + geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Eukarya 1 Codon Stretches - Distribution of codons ")+
  labs(fill= "Codons") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) + 
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = . %>% distinct(interval, Obs), 
            aes(x = interval, y = 0.25, label=Obs))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?